# Dixon Q Test - can I (all by myself) calculate the value of the Q critical?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, outliers

Im just wondering .. Everywhere I see only tables with the Qcritic as the results. Lets say I have a big set of data samples (like 1000 or more). Is then a way of mathematically calculate a Qcritic value? Is there any mathematical formula for Qcritic?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the formula for estimating them (a cubic regression in $n$, the sample size) in [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/file/n4649819/Rorabacher,_1991.pdf) paper. Dixon's Q is a small sample test: as discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28221/603) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_Q_test) there are few reasons to use the Q-test and even less when the sample size is that large.

[1]Rorabacher, D.B. (1991) "Statistical Treatment for Rejection of Deviant Values: Critical Values of Dixon Q Parameter and Related Subrange Ratios at the 95 percent Confidence Level". Anal. Chem., 63 (2), 139–146.